# Can you set S3 path in Micronaut Key Store Path?

Tags: amazon-s3, micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-aws

I have a lambda application that uses Micronaut 3.9.x (Migrated from Micronaut 1) which uses HttpClient and has a SSL configuration that points to a certificate inside my resources folder. I have the variable micronaut.http.client.ssl.key.store.path in environment variable. Can I set this to a path in S3 bucket say s3://mys3bucket/certs/client.p12?

What are the permissions that I need to add in Lambda role? TIA

Comment: Are you looking to set it programmatically or access it? and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've uploaded my certificate to S3 and I'd like to access it from the lambda function to be used in SSL Configuration.

Comment: @ThirdFon Have you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to replace NettyClientSslBuilder. You can then overwrite the load() method, and get the key store from wherever you want.

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
@Replaces(NettyClientSslBuilder.class)
public class CustomClientSslBuilder extends NettyClientSslBuilder {

    @Override
    protected KeyStore load(Optional<String> optionalType, String resource, Optional<String> optionalPassword) throws Exception {
        ...
        retrun keystore;
    }

}
```

If you want to do this on Micronaut 4.x, make sure you add `netty-incubator-codec-http3` as a dependency or else annotation processor fails on that class. This is because the class that it extends implements experimental support for HTTP 3, and requires that library to build. I filled a bug report for this:
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/10354